# Android/iOS localization in different countries

Tags: android, ios, localization

We have an app in Finland that should be launched on the Swedish app market (Play & App Store). The Finnish app is localized (translated) in Swedish and English. 
I could just launch the app as it is in Sweden but problem is there are some legal texts that differ in Sweden from Finland.

So I need these languanges:

```
fi-en  
fi-se  
fi-fi  
se-en  
se-se
```

Do I need to dublicate the app for sweden? What is best practice for this? (not just translated texts but different texts)

If I use locale the user can change this in phone settings and se-se will be the same as fi-se which is not the goal.

Comment: You just have to use different string.xml each language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, I think you just have to use different string.xml files.

For iOS, you have to internationalize storyboards (if you're using them in your app) and strings using the .strings files.

You can follow this tutorial (for iOS):
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014